# jQuery welcome message that appears until closed once (Rails 3)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3

I'd like to present a first-time user with a welcome message that appears until the user 'closes' the message one time. (via jQuery's hide method).

How can this best be accomplished? I'm using Rails 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order for the welcome message to persist between actions, you'd need to save something in the database to record whether or not the user has closed the message.  You could do this by adding a column to the User model:

```
#new_migration.rb
add_column :users, :display_welcome_message, :boolean, :default => true
```

Include a conditional statement in your layout/view to check whether it should display the welcome message:

```
<% if current_user.display_welcome_message %>
  <!-- put you welcome message here -->
<% end %>
```

Then when the user clicks the 'hide' button, you could have jquery call a controller action asynchronously:

```
$.post('/user/<%= current_user.id %>/close_welcome')
```

Then create a controller action that hides the message permanently

```
#users_controller.rb
def close_welcome
  current_user.update_attributes({:display_welcome_message => false})
end
```

You'd need to create a route for this action too:

```
#routes.rb
resources :users do
  post 'close_welcome', :on => :member
end
```

Now that I've typed this out it seems a bit long-winded, perhaps someone can come up with something much neater.  If you were going to have many different messages, your User model could get very messy - I'd probably start a new MessageAction model the belongs_to User, with a boolean field for each message type.

Answer (score 3):

Depending on the details of your site, I would recommend just using a cookie to check if the user has clicked on the close button or not.  Roughly speaking, it would be something like this:

```
if ( ! $.cookie("has_seen_message") ) {
  // show the welcome message

  $("#welcome-message .close_button").click(function() {
    $("#welcome-message").hide();
    $.cookie("has_seen_message", 1);
  });
}
```

Then you don't need to do anything at all on the Rails side.  No point in modeling/persisting UI behavior, unless it's really important.

Comment: This is a much neater solution, but it means that if the user ever deletes cookies / logs in at another computer / with another browser, they'll see the welcome message again.

Comment: Yes, it does mean that.  Using this solution means you're okay with that for sure.  A lot of sites are okay with that, stackoverflow for instance.  It really depends on the site.

Comment: Perhaps I understand the question differently; I read that @neon wanted a welcome message after the user signed up, and for it to persist until dismissed, not a welcome message when an unregistered user arrived at he site for the first time. If I understood the question correctly, I think my solution is better - it would be a bad user experience if the user gets a "welcome to the site 'new user', thanks for registering" every time they clear their cookies/login from elsewhere.

Comment: I don't think the original question is clear enough to say.  But there's nothing explicit in it about signing up or registering.  It says "present a first-time user with a welcome message" and that is not particularly clear.  Anyway, I was just suggesting an alternative, one I prefer in general, but it doesn't matter to me how he solves it.  As I said, SO is using almost exactly what I described, and it's a popular enough site for us to be bantering on it ;)

Comment: Both are well done, but I was looking for a post-sign-in solution. This solution is neater if your use-case is the scenario described above. Thanks to both for great answers.